# Segment particles into black/white image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, physics, image-segmentation, threshold

Can someone help me turn this image into a Black and White (not grayscale) image where it particles are black and the background is white? (or visa verse).

It's is not as simple as thresholding the image since the background varies in intensity and subtracting a (gaussian) blurred version does improve the situation but not enough.

best

Markus

[image]

Comment: Isn't that already black and white?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use high-pass filtering to remove the slow backgroud variations, and then apply a threshold.

I have tried a very simple form of high-pass filter: convolve with constant matrix (this is a low-pass filter) and then remove from original image.

See example result.

```
im = double(imread('tmp.jpg'));
im = im./max(im(:)); % normalize original image

N = 200; % select N of the order of background color spatial variations
imf = filter2(ones(N)/N^2,im); % normalized low-pass filter
imf = im - imf; % high-pass filter
imf = imf-min(imf(:)); % normalize between 0...
imf = imf/max(imf(:)); % ... and 1

threshold = .4; % select as appropriate
imft = imf < threshold;
imagesc(imft), colormap(gray), axis image
```

[image]